# Odds on winning a 100 club draw two consecutive months

Tags: probability

I have been lucky enough to win a 100 club draw for two consecutive months running. What are the odds of this occurring?
There are 100 persons in the draw each month, each with one ticket, therefore my chances of winning are I assume 1 in a 100 each month. There are four monetary prizes each month.
However, I have won first prize in the draw in December and January. What are the odds of this event occurring?. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, if we were to talk about rolling two 100's on 100-sided dice instead... are you asking about you as an individual having rolled two 100's in a row or are you asking about if we have millions of people who rolled these dice multiple times that at least one person rolled two 100's in a row.  The first might be improbable but the second is an almost certainty.  Next... are you talking about having just rolled the dice only twice and gotten a 100 both times... or are you talking about having rolled once a month for a million years and asking about there being two 100's in a row...

Comment: Again, the first might be improbable but the second is an almost certainty.  Coincidences happen all the time.  With so many of us and so many things happening, of course there will be coincidences that happen in our lives.

Comment: Now... if you were to adequately define the problem in mathematically rigorous language... it *sounds* like you mean to ask "*Given two independent events, $A$ and $B$ with $\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{100}$, what is the probability of $\Pr(A\cap B)$?*"  Well... by the very definition of independent events we would have $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)=\frac{1}{100}\times\frac{1}{100}=\frac{1}{10000}$

Answer (score 0):

It's very important, when asking "What's the probability of this event?", to be specific about what event you're talking about and what space of possible events you're considering. This is because people are very bad at understanding probability intuitively and while we tend to notice rare things occurring we ignore the fact that with enough rare events the chance that at least one of then happening can be reasonably high.

The probability that you win the prize in any one given month is, as you correctly say, $\frac{1}{100}$.

Assuming independence of the draws (which seems fair), the probability that you win the prize in any two consecutive months (e.g. December and January) is $\frac{1}{100} \times \frac{1}{100} = \frac{1}{10000}$, that is one in ten thousand.

However, if it is already a given that you won the prize in December, then the probability that you win in January as well *doesn't depend on the probability of winning in December*, so it's $\frac{1}{100}$ again. This is a natural consequence of the draws being independent.

Similarly, in any given month, the probability that the person who won it last month wins it again is still $\frac{1}{100}$, same as anyone else.

Additionally, the probability that the prize is won by someone *other* than last month's winner is always $\frac{99}{100}$. So if we keep track of the winners for, say, a year, then there are 11 chances to have a doubling-up of winners, so the probability that this *doesn't* happen is $\frac{99}{100} \times \frac{99}{100} \times \ldots \times \frac{99}{100} = \left( \frac{99}{100} \right)^{11} \approx 0.895$, so there's a $10.5\%$ chance that there *is* someone who wins two months in a row, which is not particularly implausible.

Comment: Thank you. Well explained